# No such DSL method 'publishHTML' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins DSL step that runs my python nosetests and creates a unittest coverage report.

Here is my jenkins stage.

```
stage ('Unit Tests') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    #. venv/bin/activate
                    export PATH=${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin:${PATH}
                    make unittest || true
                """
            }

            post {
                always {
                    junit keepLongStdio: true, testResults: 'report/nosetests.xml'
                    publishHTML target: [
                        reportDir: 'report/coverage',
                        reportFiles: 'index.html',
                        reportName: 'Coverage Report - Unit Test'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

I get this error -

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'publishHTML' found among steps.

How can I fix this error? I got this piece of code from a different repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `publishHTML` method is provided by the [HTLMPublisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher) Jenkins plugin. After installing the plugin on the primary Jenkins server, the `publishHTML` method will be available in the Jenkins Pipeline for both scripted and declarative syntax.